# Docker login problems

Tags: docker

I created a username and password on hub.docker.com but I still get authentication error when I run `docker run hello-world`, and even when I run `docker login` then enter my credentials... but it shows a success message when I do:

```
docker login -u <myusername> -p <mypassword> https://hub.docker.com
```

but even after that if I try to run:

```
docker run hello-world
```

I get the same error:

```
"error response from daemon: login attempt to https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized"
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of proxy on your network? You shouldn't need to login to pull a public image.

Comment: You don't need to be logged in to retrieve public repository images. Simply `docker run hello-world` should work. However, may be you are missing `sudo` here. Please try with `sudo docker run hello-world`.

Comment: Also you don't need to specify `https://hub.docker.com` in `docker login` command. Simply `docker login -u <myusername> -p <mypassword>` will do. You can also run it with `docker login -u <myusername>`, in this case, a password prompt will request your password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/microsoft/aspnetcore/manifests/1.1: unauthorized: incorrect username or password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993788/failed-to-build-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-microsoft-aspnetcore-manife)

Comment: Username should contain all small case. In my case I was using first char as caps. After adding all small chars I am able to login

Answer (score 5):

Try logging out first with  `docker logout`

I often find that this will at least allow me to pull images when there is some authentication issue.

Answer (score 5):

`docker logout`

`docker login`

## DONOT put email address as “username” when login from CLI. Instead USE username of you account

Answer (score 2):

A few things going wrong here. First the login command shouldn't specify a url. Instead you specify a registry. And for hub, you don't even include that:

```
docker login -u <myusername> -p <mypassword>
```

Next, the hello-world image doesn't require any authentication. If you have bad credentials setup, you can logout:

```
docker logout
```

If you still see issues after that, the most likely cause is a proxy on your network intercepting the request, and it's not docker Hub giving the 401 error, but instead it's the proxy server. You can configure docker to use a proxy by following *both* of the following:

- Configure the client: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/
- Configure the engine: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, in my case, my solution was, that I need to input the password via STDIN method as below:

- first create a file with the content is your docker password, e.g. in ~/my_password.txt
- Then login using this method:

> cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username [your_username_here] --password-stdin

Remember, your username is not your email.

Comment: This does not work if the shell is no tty. An error pops up if you use `--password-stdin` in jenkins pipeline with `sh 'docker login ...'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command first:

```
docker logout https://hub.docker.com
```

You should get an output like:

> Removing login credentials...

Then try to login.

Answer (score 0):

## Test docker login With modify Docker General Config (macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 & Docker Engine:18.09.2)

### 1. With GUI Account login

[image]

#### 1.1 With General ->  Securely store Docker logins in macOS keychain (checked)

[image]

docker login failed

[image]

#### 1.2 With General ->  Securely store Docker logins in macOS keychain (unchecked)

[image]

docker login successed

[image]

**it will Authenticating with existing credentials**.

---

### 2. With GUI Account logout

[image]

#### 2.1 With General ->  Securely store Docker logins in macOS keychain (checked)

docker login failed

[image]

#### 2.2 With General ->  Securely store Docker logins in macOS keychain (unchecked)

docker login successed

[image]

SO,

**unchecked** General->Securely store Docker logins in macOS keychain,  it solved my docker login failed problem