# failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/microsoft/aspnetcore/manifests/1.1: unauthorized: incorrect username or password

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerhub

My aspnetcore docker project builds, however when I click the Docker button ( or press F5) to run I get

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "PrepareForLaunch" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: Creating network "dockercompose1627893588_default" with the default driver
Building pswebapi
Service 'pswebapi' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/microsoft/aspnetcore/manifests/1.1: unauthorized: incorrect username or password.

For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting ---> Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: Creating network "dockercompose1627893588_default" with the default driver
Building pswebapi
Service 'pswebapi' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/microsoft/aspnetcore/manifests/1.1: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerComposeClient.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerComposeClient.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerWorkspace.<PrepareForLaunchAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.BuildTasks.DockerBaseTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets  192
```

I do have C: shared using Docker Settings.
I am using linux containers

Dockerfile is

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PsWebApi.dll"]
```

I have upgraded to the latest nuget packages.

Comment: I installed all the latest nuget packages and now have a different error  failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/microsoft/aspnetcore/manifests/1.1: unauthorized: incorrect username or password.

Comment: Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644329/docker-hello-world-authentication-error/35644630#35644630](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644329/docker-hello-world-authentication-error/35644630#35644630)
and
[https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/935](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/935)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `user id` and the *corresponding* `email` *which is used to login to dockerhub* are actually two different things in this context.

One needs the `id`, *of the username*, and not the `email` to get `images`.

---

**Resolve**

by changing between the two by doing a

`> docker logout`

on the command line then

`> docker login`

and login with your `id`.

*Note that the `id` can be found on the docker site after you login with your email.*

You will be prompted for you for the credentials. Also again, for that user name, do not use the email address.

Comment: Why we can not use the email address?

Comment: how can we streamline the process without logout and login for just download a public image?

Comment: @Franva That warrants a new question. GL

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue in latest ASP.NET Core template. And the following fix works for me.

- Open the `Package Manager Console` window.
- Run the command `docker logout`.

[image]

Then run/debug(F5) the app again.

One side note is that you need to switch to Windows container in Docker. Otherwise you will see another error: `image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform`.